# How to solve NaN value not hidden strings

Tags: javascript

I am calculating balance on web in seconds and it works if i set value in 6 digits, if it crosses million it gives me NAN.

I have tried fixedto(8),100

```
 <h3><font id="minedAmount">0</font></h3>
                                            </div>
daily =4,023.56991953/my expected calculated value

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){  
        let daily = $('#dailyAmount').text();
        let inMili = daily/864000;
        let incVal = {{isset($balance) ? $balance : 0}};
        setInterval(function(){ 
            incVal = incVal+inMili;
            $('#minedAmount').text(incVal.toFixed(8)); 
        },100);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Are you including the commas in your number input? (i.e. is your input `4,023.56991953` or `4023.56991953`?) That could make it parse incorrectly.

Comment: Provide a **runnable** [mcve] that demonstrates your issue

Comment: @IceMetalPunk no i am just showing that this value will be appear after excution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the daily into a number -

```
let daily = parseInt($('#dailyAmount').text());
```

or , `let daily = parseFloat($('#dailyAmount').text());`

Comment: Super, glad I helped :-)